# Combinatorics - falling ball through a labyrinth

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

The ball falls from point A to point B. I have some difficulty understanding the concept of what seems to be a very basic combinatorial  problem.

**a)** You can count the ways, the answer is 6. 
 
 But what is the correct mathematical notation here? 
... $2+2+2$ or $3*2$ or something else?

Now here is my thinking:

[image]

**a)** There are 3 layers (3 colors) where the ball can make turn ...

**b)** There are 5 layers (5 colors) where the ball can make turn ...

How do I apply mathematical notation here? What is the thinking process in these two cases?

Comment: With probability $1$ the ball will come out at $B$. –Counting the different possible ways is a combinatorial problem only. Or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: Yes, I wonder about different paths through a labyrinth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A path by which the ball can reach the bottom can be written as a sequence of $R$ and $L$, with $R$ indicating a movement down to the right, and $L$ a movement down to the left. For example, the path $RLLRLR$ is shown below:

[image: RLLRLR path]

In this labyrinth, the ball visits exactly 6 intersections on the way to the bottom.  The requirement that the ball end in the middle at $B$ means that the number of $R$'s and $L$'s must be equal.  So any path consists of exactly 3 $R$'s and 3 $L$'s, and we want to know how many such paths there are.

This is equivalent to the number of ways of choosing 3 objects out of a group of 6: we have 6 levels of intersections through which the ball passes, and in selecting a path we must select exactly 3 of these levels for the $L$'s, leaving the other 3 as the $R$'s. (In the example above, levels 2,3, and 5 are selected to be $L$.)  In mathematical notation this is $\binom 63,$ which is equal to $$\frac{6!}{3!3!} = \frac{720}{6\cdot 6} = 20.$$

Similarly, in the smaller labyrinth the ball passes through 4 levels of intersections and must choose exactly 2 of these to be $L$, leaving the other two to be $R$, so the answer is $$\binom42 = \frac{4!}{2!2!} = \frac{24}{2\cdot 2} = 6$$

and in general the answer for an $n\times n$ labyrinth is that there are $\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$ paths to from the top to the bottom corner.

Comment: And for $m \times n$ labyrinths it's $\binom{m+n}{m}$, being a simple manifestation of [staircase walks](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StaircaseWalk.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If you rotate the shapes 45$^\circ$ counterclockwise and view the labyrinths as grids, then your problem is the same as counting how many paths are there to move from point A to B with only down and right moves. If your grid is $n\times n$, this is equivalent to counting how many ways can $n$ be expressed as a sum of integers.

Comment: Why bother to to rotate the shape $45^\circ$?  All that gets you is having to replace the word "downward" with "down and right".  And your are mistaken about the answer being the number of ways to express $n$ as a sum of integers.  Here $n=4$, and 4 can be expressed as a sum of (positive) integers in 5 ways, not 6. The answer is actually $\binom{2n}{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

In an $m*n$ grid, you have $m+n$ slots to fill in to reach to the other corner, m of them will be L (or R) in the notation of soln above. so, fill them up -- how many distinct m slots can you pick out of $m+n$.